# VB: populating a combobox with values from a table

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2013, vb6

I have the following table:

```
    Public table As New DataTable

    table.Columns.Add("#", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Exp", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("HP", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("At", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("De", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("SA", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("SD", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Sp", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Tot", GetType(Integer))

    table.Rows.Add(1, "One", 64, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    table.Rows.Add(2, "Two", 142, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2)
    table.Rows.Add(3, "Three", 236, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3)

..........
```

The table has hundreds of entries.

I would like to populate a combobox with all the entries of the `Name` field, sorted either alphabetically or by `#` (as defined by the user).

Is there a way to easily do this, e.g. something along the lines of

```
combobox.Items.AddRange(table.Colums(2))
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the required entries using LINQ:

```
Dim values = table.AsEnumerable().
    OrderBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("#")).
    Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Name")).
    ToArray()
```

And then add them to you combobox:

```
combobox.Items.AddRange(values)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!
However, in AddRange(), `values`, instead of `val` had to be used

Comment: @Mierzen Sure. I corrected that part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, I assume a Combobox named `ComboBox1` located on `Sheet1`.
I also assume the table is named `Table1`. You will need to adjust as required.

This solution is VBA.

```
Sub SortedComboFromTableColumn()
    Dim rng As Range

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For Each rng In Range("Table1[Name]")
            .Add rng.Value
        Next
        .Sort

        Sheets(1).ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.toarray())
    End With
End Sub
```